# Visual Studio 2010: Unit Test: Debugger not starting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, debugging

I am trying to debug a unit test.  I set a breakpoint in my test function, put my cursor in the test function, and click the button "Debug Tests in Current Context Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T".

It looks like it is trying to start:
"Test run pending Results 0/1 passed Items(s) checked: 0"

But after about a minute I get this error:

"Test run "[computer name] could not be executed. Timed out waiting for the process that runs tets to initialize."

I can run the tests without the debugger.  But every test I run I get this error.

How do I fix this or where can I look for more information on what process died and how to start it?

Comment: Just a hunch: Check that the project you are testing, and the test project are running under the same version of the .Net Framework (properties for the project, and Application, look for "Target Framework"). If the two do not match, that can cause some strange issues similar to this.

Comment: The unit test project and the source project are both .NET 4 frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in the unit test you are trying to debug and launch the test `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`
You should see a window appear asking you to select the debugger to attach to the process.

I don't know the exact method you are refering to, but it looks like a window that is not visible is expecting some input from you. Maybe the same window as the one the method above would trigger.

Comment: I had to run (with out the debugger), but then it asked to connect the debugger.  This is a good workaround.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to delete the *.suo file.

I created a new project in the old solution and it failed.
I created a new solution with a new project and it worked.
I added the new project that worked into the old solution and it failed.

This indicated that it was an error in the solution, not a project.

The *.suo file was not in SVN, so I closed Visual Studio, moved it, and restarted Visual Studio.

Now the unit tests can be debugged.  I was also getting an error when I was trying to run the application that I was trying to unit test.  This was the clue that led me down the path of creating a fresh project.